# Accessing webpack/bundled React Class from .html file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it not possible to access already 'built' components within the html file that the build is linked to?

I am trying the following -

In bundle.js

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

     var Titles = React.createClass({
       render() {

          return (
             <div>
                <h1>{this.props.headerProp}</h1>
                <h2>{this.props.contentProp}</h2>
             </div>
          );
       }
    });
```

In my html page -

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>

    <div id="con"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js'"></script>

      <script type="text/jsx">

    ReactDOM.render(<Titles headerProp = "Header from props..." contentProp = "Content
       from props..."/>, document.getElementById('con'));
        </script>
```

But console outputs React is not defined.

I have even tried to set react globally within the bundle -

```
window.React = React;
```

And calling it with window. prefixed but yields the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're mentiong a `bundle.js` file with a snippet containing `commonjs` style imports, I'm assuming you're using Webpack.

I have some considerations about your code.

1. `bundle.js` file will not expose any module as global. That includes React and any other module you might `require` inside the bundle. There isn't goint to be `window.ModuleName`. However, these module are accessible in the Browser via [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) because Webpack will export modules as UMD, that is, they will be accessible through either `commonjs` or `AMD` (Require.js).
2. I'm pretty sure that, if in the **entry point** of your webpack configuration file, you do something like `var React = require("react"); window.React = React`, that's actually going to work.
3. There's a Webpack module meant to expose modules globally (like in `window.x`) in a more ellegant way than (2) called [expose-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader). You should take a look at it.
4. You should really try to avoid doing what you're trying to do. In your `entry.js` file (the entry point of  your webpack configuration) should be responsible for doing something like `ReactDOM.render(..., document.getElementById("#app"))`. So that, **just by including your bundle, the app will render automatically**. This is what everybody does.
5. `JSXTransformer.js` as well as the `<script type="text/jsx">` have been deprecated a long time ago. Now you're supposed to use Babel to compile React.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice!

Comment: This question seems to be pretty valid because, you'd need to expose React class if you were integrating a React app within a different framework/library like ng or vue.